# TweenMax.js transform rotate doesn't work in IE 9

Tags: html, svg, gsap

I am trying to animate few Svg elements( Windmill , Door Open) using Tweenmax.js

The Windmill rotation works fine but the door opening animation doesn't work at all in Internet Explorer 9.

Here's my code :

```js
var dooropen = $('#door-open');

var windmill = $('#windmill');

function DoorOpen() {
  TweenMax.to(dooropen, 3, {
    rotationY: 180,
    transformOrigin: "0% 0%"
  });
}


function rotateFan() {
  TweenMax.to(windmill, 40, {
    rotation: 360,
    transformOrigin: "51% 64%"
  });
}





$('.run').click(function() {
  DoorOpen();
  rotateFan();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="Layer_1" width="887.996" height="567.947">

  <path fill="#231F20" d="M89.917 99.025h31.58v468.42h-31.58z" />

  <g id="windmill" fill="#FFF" stroke="#231F20" stroke-miterlimit="10">
    <path d="M105.706 116.57s-50.877-56.142 0-115.79c0 0 47.368 57.894 0 115.79zM105.707 116.57s73.15-19.732 103.088 52.726c0 0-73.114 15.808-103.088-52.727z" />
    <path d="M105.707 116.57S76.25 186.372.71 165.385c0 0 32.528-67.36 104.997-48.817z" />
  </g>

  <path fill="#FFF" stroke="#231F20" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M485.496 162.376h402v402h-402z" />
  <path fill="#231F20" d="M567.496 266.376h246v298h-246z" />

  <g id="door-open">
    <path fill="#B51543" d="M567.496 266.376h246v298h-246z" />
    <path fill="#841C3F" d="M791.496 419.376c0 2.762-2.238 5-5 5h-26c-2.762 0-5-2.238-5-5v-26c0-2.762 2.238-5 5-5h26c2.762 0 5 2.238 5 5v26z" />
  </g>

</svg>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="run">Run</a>
```

Comment: I think **[this](http://greensock.com/forums/topic/11277-is-transformorigin-supported-in-ie9/#entry45624)** should help you i.e. **two-value** syntax for IE9 for the `transformOrigin` property.

Comment: @Tahir Ahmed is right! A two-value syntax is preferred,e, even though the third parameter is accepeted. The third value will automatically default to zero anyway, since that is the default value from the spec 0. And is only necessary when using 3D transforms, since it aligns itself to the z-axis. But it looks like your issue is that your mixing string values with a numerical one. The default transform-origin are percentages `50% 50% 0`. So also it is best to stick with percentage based or numerical values for transform-origin. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your issue is that your mixing string values with a numerical ones. The default transform-origin are percentages `50% 50% 0`. So also it is best to stick with percentage based or numerical values for transform-origin in GSAP.

A two-value syntax is preferred like @Tahir Ahmed commented above. Even though the third parameter is accepted. The third value will automatically default to zero anyway, since that is the default value from the spec `0`. And is only necessary when using 3D transforms, since it aligns itself to the z-axis. Which you cant use in SVG, since SVG does not support CSS 3D Transforms.

Have a look at the transform-origin spec:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin

Try this:

```
var dooropen = $('#door-open');
var windmill = $('#windmill');

function DoorOpen() {
    TweenMax.to(dooropen, 3, {
        rotationY: 180,
        transformOrigin: "0% 0%" /* top and left, omit 0 since is the default */
    });
}

function rotateFan() {
    TweenMax.to(windmill, 40, {
        rotation: 360,
        transformOrigin: "51% 64%"
    });
}

$('.run').click(function() {
   DoorOpen();
   rotateFan();
});
```

`tranform-origin` keyword equivalents:

- left = **0%**
- center = **50%**
- right = **100%**
- top = **0%**
- bottom = **100%**

Also check out the [CSSPlugin Docs](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Plugins/CSSPlugin/) and the use of SVG transformOrigin

http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Plugins/CSSPlugin/

GSAP **svgOrigin** property, taken from [CSSPlugin Docs](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Plugins/CSSPlugin/):

[Only for SVG elements] Works exactly like `transformOrigin` but it uses the SVG's global coordinate space instead of the element's local coordinate space. This can be very useful if, for example, you want to make a bunch of SVG elements rotate around a common point. You can either define an `svgOrigin` or a transformOrigin, not both (for obvious reasons).

[See codepen example here of svgOrigin](http://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/06716224865c2c536cee5b4222d771ee).

So you can do `TweenLite.to(svgElement, 1, {rotation:270, svgOrigin:"250 100"})` if you'd like to rotate svgElement as though its origin is at `x:250, y:100` in the SVG canvas's global coordinates. Units are not required. It also records the value in a `data-svg-origin` attribute so that it can be parsed back in. `svgOrigin` doesn't accommodate percentage-based values.

Comment: Hi Jonathan i tried both ways but it still doesn't work. The Codepen demo is working fine in IE 9 but not mine.

Comment: Are you testing in real IE9 or is an emulation mode. Also In @Jack answer below did you try not use rotateY like he advised, since SVG ignores 3D transforms?

Comment: I have a separate windows machine for testing purpose which has IE11, so ya im testing it in an Emulation mode.  Im justing looking for an output for a door opening in a perspective way. if 3d doesn't works out then i think i will have to just decrease the width of that door from right so that it looks like its opening.

Comment: usually to fake a 3D effect using 2D Transfoms .. you could use either `skewX` or `skewY`

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to animate the rotationY of an SVG element, that's the problem - the SVG spec does **NOT** allow 3D at all. That's not a GSAP problem or limitation - it's literally the SVG spec. Some webkit browsers do technically recognize 3D CSS transforms, but that's non-standard and it definitely isn't supported in IE because IE ignores all CSS transforms on SVG elements. Transforms are supposed to be applied via the "transform" **attribute** which, again, does not support 3D.

My advice: don't do 3D in SVG. I wish I had better news for you.

Comment: Thanks jack for the reply, Im justing looking for an output for a door opening in a perspective way. if 3d doesn't works out then i think i will have to just decrease the width of that door from right so that it looks like its opening.